# Could not resolve com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, moshi

Getting this error and unable to build Gradle file.

Android Studio Version : ***Bumblebee Latest Patch***

Gradle Plugin Version : ***7.1.2***

Gradle Version : ***7.2***

I already tried adding `android.jetifier.ignorelist=moshi-1.13.0` in Gradle properties but it's not working.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error? Have you added the mavenCentral repository?

Comment: In my case it worked by adding these lines in the file `gradle.properties`: 

- `android.enableJetifier=true`
- `android.jetifier.ignorelist=moshi-1.14.0` (Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX)

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate caches and restart Android Studio?